# Scala wrap generic anonymous class

Tags: java, scala, closures

I'm trying to make this code nicer by using scala closures:

```
  SQLiteQueue queue = new SQLiteQueue(databaseFile);
  queue.start();    
  queue.execute(new SQLiteJob<Object>() {
    protected Object job(SQLiteConnection connection) throws SQLiteException {
      connection.exec(...);
      return null;
    }
  });
```

I subclassed SQLiteQueue and added an overload to the execute function:

```
def execute[T](action: SQLiteConnection => T) {
    val job = new SQLiteJob[T] {
        override def job(conn:SQLiteConnection):T = {
            action(conn)
        }
    }
    super.execute(job)
}
```

so I can use it something like this:

```
queue.execute { conn => do something with conn}
```

But I get this compiler error at `super.execute(job)`

```
error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteJob[T]] 
do not conform to method execute's type parameter bounds [T,J <: 
com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteJob[T]]
```

the execute function I'm calling there looks like this: `public <T, J extends SQLiteJob<T>> J execute(J job)`

Comment: Can you try with `super.execute[T, SQLiteJob[T]](job)` ?

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles that worked! wanna put it as an answer?

Comment: Despite my wrong answer, I keep my advice: it's good practice to use the `=` in `def something = {...}` when you intent return something other than `Unit`.

Comment: @Damian: sure. I avoided adding it right away because I had not tested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the type parameters when calling execute:

```
super.execute[T, SQLiteJob[T]](job)
```